# Symfony2 index routes 2 parameters

Tags: php, symfony

I want have this urls:

```
example.com
example.com/category
example.com/category/name
```

My routes:

```
default_page:
    path:     /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:index }
default_page:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:index }
default_page:
    path:     /{name}/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:index }
```

Work properly only

```
example.com/category
```

What is wrong with my routes ?

Error is:

```
No route found for "GET /category/name"
No route found for "GET /"
```

Comment: I think it may be because you have them all set at `default_page` ? Or was that just for the example?

Comment: @ChadSikorra but this may be 1 page `indexAction`

Comment: Yes, but they still need different names for YAML otherwise some will be ignored and you will get unexpected results. Or maybe I'm not understanding something obvious? Time to grab my morning coffee haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make your internal name of the route unique and it should work properly.

```
default_page_X:
    path:     /{name}
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:index }
default_page_Y:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:index }
default_page_Z:
    path:     /{name}/{category}
    defaults: { _controller: CatalogWebBundle:Default:index }
```

Answer (score 3):

braces are for variables. When you type .com/category it will go into your first route with "category" as value of the variable name

Comment: Yes, I need pass variables by get `example.com/category1/name1`

Comment: unless you're in prod on a server and you don't have rewrite rules ?

Comment: I have all permisssion, it's my own dev server